# Angular Adal redirect URL is lost on the road at login

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect, adal.js

In my Angular application (5.1.1) I'm using Adal.js (1.0.29) to authenticate to Azure AD. When a user is not logged in and tries to access the website, logically he will be redirected to login, but when he is authenticated successfully the requested URL (redirect) is lost.
For the setup of Adal.js I followed this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-adal-with-angular2/

The URL that the user is trying to access is guarded by CanActivate, so it will redirect to the adal login process. As shown in the code, at this time the redirect URL is still there. I suspect that is lost in the this.context.login method.

```
const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
     queryParams: { 'redirectUrl': route.url }
};

if (!this.adalService.userInfo || !this.adalService.accessToken) {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['login'], navigationExtras);
    return false;
}
```

```
login() {
   if  (this.context.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {
       this.context.handleWindowCallback();
   }
   this.context.login();
}
```

So I would like to know how to get the redirectUrl back when a user is successfully authenticated.

Comment: How about saving it in local storage and retrieving after successful login?

Comment: @xdecdec At the authentication guard, I created sessionStorage property, which I get back to check when login is successfull.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RouterStateSnapshot to get the url in canActivate guard, and then pass this to login as navigationExtras with your router.navigate method.

Then you can pull this down into your login component and redirect the user onto the correct page once they have authenticated. Example of what i mean below.

```
canActivate(
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
)
this.router.navigate(['login'], {queryParams: {redirect: state.url}})
```

Then in login component grab params

```
this.redirect = this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
if(params['redirect']) {
this.redirect = params['redirect']
}
}

login() {
if(typeof(this.redirect !=='undefined) {
this.router.navigate[this.redirect]
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @xdecdec I created a sessionStorage property at the authentication guard with the redirect url. After a successfull login I get this property back to redirect to the correct page.